# Twilio Conference Call: how to add options menu

Tags: twilio, conference

Hello to Twilio Developer Evangelists here :)

Is there an easy way to add options menu (not sure if I call it right) to conference call, so all participants have ability to perform some actions by pressing numbers.

At this moment the only way I can see how this can be implemented - add outgoing call with  to conference call. But I'm still playing with it, so not sure if this would work...

Thank you!

Comment: Hello! I'm a Twilio developer evangelist, here to help! What do you have for setting up your conference call so far, is it TwiML that responds when people dial into a number? And how are you looking to make the options work? Should there be a menu before the caller enters the conference call?

Comment: @philnash, I'm using TwiML to respond.
<Dial action="conferenceEnd.php?callerId=<?php echo $callerId;?>">
<Conference startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="true"> myConference </Conference></Dial>
  And I'm looking to make the options available after the callers entered the conference call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here :)

One way I've done this before is by using the hangupOnStar attribute of the `<Dial>` verb.

As long as you've not provided an action parameter on the `<Dial>` verb, if the caller hits `*` while in the conference room, Twilio will disconnect them from the conference room and execute the next verb in your Twilio document, which could be a `<Gather>` containing a menu:

```
<Response>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">
        <Conference>YourConference</Conference>
    </Dial>
    <Gather action="http://example.com/processConferenceMenu?confName=YourConference" numDigits="1">
        <Say>To mute all participants, press one</Say>
        <Say>To leave the conference, press two</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

In the `processConferenceMenu` endpoint you would process whatever value the caller has input durung the gather and then if needed put then right back into the same conference room.

I've created systems which let users use `*6` (the standard self-mute command) without any menu prompts and the lag between when the user leaves and then re-enters the conference muted was barely noticeable.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Devin, thank you! I didn't think about this way to implement a menu.
You mentioned that this was "one way I've have done this". Does it mean that there are other ways to add a menu to conference call? :)