# Twilio Dial verb with hangupOnStar, action is triggered without star being pressed?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

We're experiencing a production issue where users have triggered a `Dial` verb action without pressing star, while `hangUpOnStar` is set to `true` and remaining on the call. This has recently been reported by clients in the US.

We haven't been able to reproduce this issue ourselves, but my colleague tells me it is present in the call logs.

We have we arrived at the following scenarios as to why this occurs...

- Bug in the twilio platform.
- User error, they have pressed star.
- An issue with certain handsets.

Here's some example code which we use...

```
<Response>
    <Say language="en-GB" voice="woman">Welcome person....</Say>
    <Dial callerId="record-from-answer" record="record-from-answer" hangupOnStar="true" 
        action="http://ourserver/handler">
        <Conference beep="false" startConferenceOnEnter="true" muted="false" 
             waitUrl="http://com.twilio.music.classical.s3.amazonaws.com/ClockworkWaltz.mp3" 
             waitMethod="GET">57354</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

So here we're connecting to a conference and once star is pressed the action is called and the conference is disconnected. This works as documented most of the time.

However as mentioned the `Dial` action is being triggered when is **shouldn't** be.

We have tried to work around this issue, but there seems no property on the `Dial` verb to allow for this.

Also I've seen workarounds like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019989/12506160
Which use `Dial` with `hangUpOnStar` with no action, to pass on a `Gather` verb.

Which would allow the caller to re-connect to a conference, but this won't work as `hangupOnStar` could still be called with this scenario / issue.

Obviously there is no other way for the user to interact within a conference as stated in the documentation.

Comment: JMWC2019, you will need to open a ticket with Twilio (help@twilio.com or via the Twilio Console) and provide recent (less then 48 hours old) examples and CallSID's where this behavior happening (this is critical to finding the root cause). They will then being able to investigate further. Also, a participant can be in a conference for a maximum of 4 hours. Is it possible the participant is hitting that constraint and being disconnected or someone else in the conference has endConferenceOnExit set. Also look for any seemingly related Debugger messages when a user reports this issue.